# Need to maintained a resized value of datagridview column after closing form /open it again

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, windows-controls

Need to set a resized value by user of datagridview column such that after closing form on which datagridview control present & open it again so the resized value of column should be the same as set while closing the form.

code i tried:
1]

```
dataGridView1.Columns[col.Name].DisplayIndex = col.DisplayIndex + 3;
                dataGridView1.Columns[col.Name].Visible = col.Visible;
                  dataGridView1.Columns[col.Name].Width = col.Width;
```

2]

`dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells)`;

3]

```
 dataGridView1.Columns[col.Name].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
            int widthCol = dataGridView1.Columns[col.Name].Width;
            dataGridView1.Columns[col.Name].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dataGridView1.Columns[col.Name].Width = widthCol;
```

Properties i tried:

```
AutoResizeColumns with fill
```

Comment: It (sort of) sounds like you want to persist user selections of column sizes (and perhaps order)?  If so you need to write down all the sizes and re-apply them each time the form opens

Comment: user can resize column size to any value,How to get this value & where to maintain/store it so after form open i can assign it ?